# iOS: Editing items in a TableView Issues

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I'm trying to write the delete edit behavior for the rows in a tableview. However, when I hit the delete key after selecting a row, the row is not deleted from the tableView. When I try to do it a second time, I get an error saying an unexpected nil value was found.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {   // Handle the Delete action
        // Obtain the name of the genre of movie to be deleted
        let genre: String = genres[indexPath.section]

        // Obtain the list of movies in the genre as AnyObject
        let movies: AnyObject? = applicationDelegate.dict_Genres_dict2[genre]
        let movArray: [String] = movies?.allKeys as! [String] //The nil value is unwrapped on this line
        // Typecast the AnyObject to Swift array of String objects
        var moviesOfGenre: Array<String> = movArray 

        // Delete the identified movie at row
        moviesOfGenre.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        if moviesOfGenre.count == 0 {
            // If no movie remains in the array after deletion, then we need to also delete the genre
            applicationDelegate.dict_Genres_dict2.removeObjectForKey(genre)

            // Since the dictionary has been changed, obtain the genre names again
            genres = applicationDelegate.dict_Genres_dict2.allKeys as! [String]

            // Sort the genre names within itself in alphabetical order
            genres.sortInPlace { $0 < $1 }
        }
        else {
            // At least one more movie remains in the array; therefore, the genre stays.

            // Update the new list of movie for the genre in the NSMutableDictionary
            applicationDelegate.dict_Genres_dict2.setValue(moviesOfGenre, forKey: genre)
        }

        // Reload the rows and sections of the Table View 
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I have marked which line I am receiving the nil value. Any push in the right direction would be most helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the array item. You need remove that item from the table too.When you try to delete the array item again, it shows nil, because that item is not available, but the table didn't remove that item from the view.So you need to remove it from table too...

```
        genres.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) // or section , delete according to your app   
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

why do you take section of the item  that you want to delete. You didn't delete the genre item from the table. You only deleted the moviesOfGenre. You need to delete the table view item also( genre ). Remove the genre also from the table.

Also you can use swipe to delete function :-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == .Delete) {
   // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.genres.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row) // also remove an array object if exists.
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: I added that and now I am getting a NSInternal Inconsistency Exception. How am I supposed to account for the change in number of rows/elements to fix that?

Comment: Your advice of removing the data from the source helped! Thank you!